# Access denied for user MySQL in Django

Tags: python, mysql, django

I have created a Django app and which uses MySQL. The settings.py file in the database sections is:

```
DATABASES = {
    'cdraccess': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': os.environ.get('CDR_DB_NAME', 'portal2'),
        'USER': os.environ.get('CDR_DB_USER', 'cdraccess'),
        'HOST': os.environ.get('CDR_DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'CONN_MAX_AGE': 0,
        'PASSWORD': os.environ.get('CDR_DB_PASSWORD', ''),
    },
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}
```

I run the app like:

```
CDR_DB_PASSWORD='password' CDR_DB_HOST='host_name' ./manage.py runserver
```

but I get the following error:

> Access denied for user 'cdraccess'@'host_ip_here' (using password:
>   NO)")

I tried to access the database from terminal, like:

```
   $ mysql --host=[host_name] --user=cdraccess -p portal2
```

and worked fine.

What is going wrong in here? And what does this "(using password: NO)" mean?

Comment: I didnot know you can setup db like this and start app like this...

Comment: does your app work when you hardcode the password into settings.py?

Comment: @DerekKwok, no it doesn't. there is the same error message even when I hardcode the password.

Comment: try this: run `python manage.py shell`. Once inside the shell, type `from django import db` and `db.connections.databases['cdraccess']`. This will print out the database settings Django uses when your app is running. Can you confirm if you see the password in there?

Comment: @DerekKwok, I can see the password and everything looks fine. But I still get the same error.